# Inline Table Join Multiplying Results

Tags: sql, left-join

The below query joins two views and one inline table to another inline table. When I run the query without table FI all of the SUM values return correctly, however, when I run the query with table FI all of the SUM values from `vw_Interactions` are multiplied and returned incorrect (SUM values from `vw_LeadInteractions` are not affected).

`vw_Interactions` is a transactional log and returns a 1 in each column where that measure is true (ex: a 1 is returned in `I.[Call]` where a phone call was logged), and `vw_LeadInteractions` is the same except it returns the Client's ID.

I did several hours of research and found that inline tables can cause issues when joining (the Cartesian product?), however I wasn't able to understand how those answers were relevant to this query.

Can someone explain why that when table FI is included in this query that it multiplies the SUM values of everything from `vw_Interactions`? And then how do I fix my query so this does not happen?

This query is for my employer's outbound call center to measure what's happening during each 'round' of calling.

```
/* Parameters */
DECLARE @StartDatetime AS Date
    SET @StartDatetime = '06/01/13'
DECLARE @EndDatetime AS Date
    SET @EndDatetime = '05/31/14'

/* Dataset */
SELECT R.[RoundsGoal]
      ,R.[RoundNumber]
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT R.[Client_Id]) AS 'Leads'
      ,ISNULL(SUM(I.[Call]), 0) AS 'Calls'
      ,ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT LI.[Call]), 0) AS 'CallLeads'
      ,ISNULL(SUM(FI.[FirstCall]), 0) AS 'FirstCalls'
      ,ISNULL(SUM(I.[DecisionMakerCall]), 0) AS 'DecisionMakerCalls'
      ,ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT LI.[DecisionMakerCall]), 0) AS 'DecisionMakerCallLeads'
      ,ISNULL(SUM(FI.[FirstDecisionMakerCall]), 0) AS 'FirstDecisionMakerCalls'
      ,ISNULL(SUM( I.[LeftMessageCall]), 0) AS 'LeftMessageCalls'
      ,ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT LI.[LeftMessageCall]), 0) AS 'LeftMessageLeads'
      ,ISNULL(SUM(FI.[FirstLeftMessageCall]), 0) AS 'FirstLeftMessageCalls'
      ,ISNULL(SUM(I.[NoAnswerCall]), 0) AS 'NoAnswerCalls'
      ,ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT LI.[NoAnswerCall]), 0) AS 'NoAnswerCallLeads'
      ,ISNULL(SUM(FI.[FirstNoAnswerCall]), 0) AS 'FirstNoAnswerCalls'
FROM (
    SELECT RD.[Client_Id]
          ,ISNULL(UF1.[NumericCol], 0) AS 'RoundsGoal'
          ,COUNT(RD.[RoundDate]) OVER(PARTITION BY RD.[Client_Id] ORDER BY RD.[RoundDate] ASC) AS 'RoundNumber'
          ,RD.[RoundDate]
    FROM [dbo].[vw_RoundDates] RD
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[AMGR_User_Fields] UF1 ON RD.[Client_Id] = UF1.[Client_Id] AND UF1.[Type_Id] = 140 --Rounds Goal TypeId
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[AMGR_User_Field_Defs] UFD1 ON UF1.[Type_Id] = UFD1.[Type_Id] AND UF1.[Code_Id] = UFD1.[Code_Id]
    WHERE RD.[RoundDate] >= @StartDatetime AND RD.[RoundDate] <= @EndDatetime
) R
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[vw_Interactions] I ON R.[Client_Id] = I.[Client_Id] AND R.[RoundDate] = CAST(I.[Created] AS DATE)
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[vw_LeadInteractions] LI ON R.[Client_Id] = LI.[Client_Id] AND R.[RoundDate] = CAST(LI.[Created] AS DATE)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT I.[Client_Id]
          ,CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN I.[Call] = 1 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY I.[Client_Id], I.[Call] ORDER BY I.[Created] ASC) ELSE NULL END) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS 'FirstCall'
          ,CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN I.[DecisionMakerCall] = 1 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY I.[Client_Id], I.[DecisionMakerCall] ORDER BY I.[Created] ASC) ELSE NULL END) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS 'FirstDecisionMakerCall'
          ,CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN I.[LeftMessageCall] = 1 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY I.[Client_Id], I.[LeftMessageCall] ORDER BY I.[Created] ASC) ELSE NULL END) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS 'FirstLeftMessageCall'
          ,CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN I.[NoAnswerCall] = 1 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY I.[Client_Id], I.[NoAnswerCall] ORDER BY I.[Created] ASC) ELSE NULL END) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS 'FirstNoAnswerCall'
          ,[Created]
    FROM [dbo].[vw_Interactions] I
) FI ON R.[Client_Id] = FI.[Client_Id] AND R.[RoundDate] = CAST(FI.[Created] AS DATE)
GROUP BY R.[RoundsGoal] 
        ,R.[RoundNumber]
ORDER BY R.[RoundsGoal] ASC
        ,R.[RoundNumber] ASC
```

Here is the correct results set without table FI. Notice the Calls on row 23 equals 135,110.

[image: Correct results]
Here is the incorrect results, that include table FI. Notice the Calls on row 23 are multiplied to 1,561,038.

[image: Incorrect results]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - if you [provide a small sample that is able to reproduce your problem](http://sscce.org/) others can help you faster. Preparing an sqlfiddle also increases your chances to get quick help.

Comment: One way to debug is to comment out the group by clause and take out the aggregate functions and analyse the un-grouped data. You may notice then if you are getting more rows back from a certain join than expected. Add and take out the FI join and analyse the un-grouped data returned. Good luck.